# Changin input class on angular model property changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have one input of text type, and I need that this input become on span depending of the value of a property of my model. So, the jquery function that I have for become a input in span is:

```
$('.read').replaceWith(function(){
   return '<span class='+this.className+'>'+this.value+'</span>'    
});
```

And the ng directive that I have used is: **ng-change**:

```
<input id="1" type="text" ng-model="src.ViewModel.Model.DataA" ng-change="src.search(src.ViewModel.Model.DataA)"/>
```

The method is:

```
theController.prototype.search = function(data){  
    if (data == 1)
    {
        theModel.DataA = data;
        $('.read').replaceWith(function(){
            return '<span class='+this.className+'>'+this.value+'</span>';
        });    
    }
};
```

And the input that must changes is:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="src.ViewModel.Model.DataB" ng-class="{'read': src.ViewModel.Model.DataA == 1}" />
```

But it does not works, so, how I can solve that ??

Here is my Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcastelblanco/3n8o3ud7/2/)

Any help or suggestion, please ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're doing what you're doing and I suspect that there's a better way to accomplish your goal.

Having said that, the problem is that in your search function you're looking for an element with class `.read` but that element is not there. `ng-class` would set the `.read` class after this digest cycle runs which means after the search function runs.

You can fix this by using $timeout like:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $('.read').replaceWith(function(){
            return '<span class='+this.className+'>'+this.value+'</span>';
        });    
    }
});
```

This will make it so your code runs in the next $digest cycle, after the `.read` class has been added.

Also, initialize your DataA property with something other than 1. Otherwise you have to first set the textbox to something else and then to 1 so that `ng-change` triggers.

Answer (score 0):

@freddy i put a watch on the element which you wish to change.
Something like this

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
        //here watchme is the input you wish to change into span
        return $("#watchme").hasClass('read');
    }, function () {
        $('.read').replaceWith(function () {
            return '<span>' + $scope.ViewModel.DataA + '</span>'
        });
    });
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3n8o3ud7/5/
Hope this solves your purpose.